# Встраивание Lua в C++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt, lua

Есть приложение `C++` `Qt` и в него нужно встроить логику, написанную на `Lua`. Нашел статью на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/197300/), в которой описывается как это сделать, но она не первой свежести и, вероятно, в того момента что-то поменялось.
Я создал функцию, которая как раз и должна работать с `Lua`

```
lua_State* state = luaL_newstate();  
std::string filename("Gauss.lua");

if(luaL_loadfile(state, filename.c_str()) || lua_pcall(state, 0, 0, 0))
{
    qDebug() << "Скрипт не был загружен " << filename.c_str();
    state = nullptr;
}
```

Но скрипт не подгружается и кроме этого факта никакого фидбека нет, поэтому ума не приложу откуда ноги растут.

Точнее говоря, у меня 2 скрипта, `Gauss.lua` и `matrix.lua`. Первый включает в себя второй. Не знаю важно ли это, но при попытке подключения второго скрипта таких проблем не возникает.

P.S. Буду очень благодарен, если в добавок подскажите хорошую литературу на эту тему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В книге [Programming in Lua by Roberto Ierusalimschy](https://www.lua.org/pil/24.1.html) приводится немного расширенный пример простой инициализации интерпретатора Lua:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"
int main (void) {
    char buff[256];
    int error;
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate(); /* открывает Lua */
    luaL_openlibs(L); /* открывает стандартные библиотеки */
    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff) , stdin) != NULL) {
        error = luaL_loadstring(L, buff) || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0) ;
        if (error) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
            lua_pop(L, 1); /* снять сообщение об ошибке со стека */
        }
    }
    lua_close(L) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь видно, что в случае ошибки, со стека Lua получается сообщение функцией `lua_tostring(L, -1)`. Возможно, это поможет вам найти проблему.

Ещё тут отдельной командой инициализируются стандартные библиотеки. Может, вам не хватает именно их.

P.S. Книга есть и на русском языке под названием "Программирование на языке LUA". Автор: Роберту Иерузалимски.