# Qt-диалог & SQL на Lua

Tags: c++, sql, qt, postgresql, lua

Хочу встроить `Lua` в свою программу, написанную на `Qt/C++`. Нашел пока статьи и обсуждения о простом встраивании `Lua` в `Си` программу ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654104/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-lua-%D0%B2-c-qt)).

Но мне простого встраивания маловато. Нужно мочь в загружаемом скрипте на `Lua` строить графические диалоги `Qt`, получать от них данные, по этим данным делать запросы к БД по уже существующему коннекту Qt-программы. Все это нужно для реализации гибкой и расширяемой системы отчетности.

Пока нашел какой-то проект [`torch/qtlua`](https://github.com/torch/qtlua), но он кажется уж очень староват?!

Что посоветуете? Может есть что-то более свежее/актуальное? Или придется брать и дорабатывать тот, который я указал выше?

Comment: это не очень то похоже на "встраивание" lua в приложение, больше похоже на то, что вы хотите получить lua api над qt. На вашем месте я бы подумал: а правильно ли вы цель определили?

Comment: Ну не знаю, на что это похоже больше. Но что именно нужно - я описал в самом вопросе.

Comment: `Нужно мочь в загружаемом скрипте на Lua строить графические диалоги Qt` - ну напишите на Си функции-обёртки над Qt и зарегистрируйте эти обёртки в Lua